# Diagnosing WAN performance & peering issues without a second ISP uplink as a comparison?

Tags: performance, internet, isp, wide-area-network, peering

**Background:**

I am able to access Twitter & Serverfault from work (using Level3) with no problems.   However when I use RCN I get crummy service and am not able to load the page.  Page reloads provide no positive effect, however switching back and forth between Wifi and LAN access often gets some data through.

I know the issue is not "local" because I'm able to use the cable modem in wifi or LAN mode with Level3 with no issues.  If it matters I'm in Queens, the server is in Midtown.

Therefore I am assuming that there is a router on the RCN connection or piece of infrastructure that is overloaded, or problematic.

**Question**

- Now that I feel confident that the issue is with RCN equipment, is there any TCP / IP statistic that I can look at that will reflect this issue *without* having to use a different ISP as a comparison?
- Is there any website or general up/down ISP peering website that can tell me the utilization capacity of rcn, mfnx, or above.net?
- Since I get sporadic network connectivity by switching between LAN and Wifi when accessing an "above.net" server how is that different from a page reload, which provides minimal if any results?  What could my RCN provided wifi bridge be doing differently that causes upstream devices to temporarily permit some connections though?

**OSX Terminal trace to twitter.com**

```
traceroute to twitter.com (199.59.149.230), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  1.277 ms  1.083 ms  0.987 ms
 2  10.21.192.1 (10.21.192.1)  11.795 ms  20.306 ms  10.652 ms
 3  x.x.x.x (x.x.xx)  16.279 ms  12.181 ms  21.494 ms
 4  tge0-1-0-0.core2.nyw.ny.rcn.net (207.172.15.89)  13.070 ms
    tge0-1-0-0.core1.nyw.ny.rcn.net (207.172.15.84)  11.621 ms
    tge0-0-0-0.core1.nyw.ny.rcn.net (207.172.15.75)  24.185 ms
 5  tge0-0-0-2.core2.phdl.pa.rcn.net (207.172.19.228)  16.799 ms
    tge0-1-0-2.core2.phdl.pa.rcn.net (207.172.19.20)  28.493 ms
    tge0-1-0-2.core1.phdl.pa.rcn.net (207.172.19.216)  12.474 ms
 6  tge0-0-0-2.core1.lnh.md.rcn.net (207.172.19.227)  22.619 ms
    tge0-0-0-2.core2.lnh.md.rcn.net (207.172.19.11)  25.869 ms
    tge0-1-0-3.core2.lnh.md.rcn.net (207.172.19.225)  21.040 ms
 7  tge2-3.border1.eqnx.va.rcn.net (207.172.19.7)  16.492 ms
    tge1-4.border1.eqnx.va.rcn.net (207.172.19.179)  19.932 ms
    tge2-4.border1.eqnx.va.rcn.net (207.172.19.205)  28.127 ms
 8  ge-4-1-0.mpr1.iad10.us.mfnx.net (206.223.115.86)  19.219 ms  27.854 ms  15.894 ms
 9  209.66.115.18.t01337-05.above.net (209.66.115.18)  18.263 ms  21.475 ms  23.380 ms
10  ae60.pao1-cr2.twttr.com (199.16.159.87)  81.884 ms  88.065 ms  88.222 ms
11  ae51.smf1-er1.twttr.com (199.16.159.29)  82.919 ms  91.152 ms
    xe-11-0-0.smf1-er2.twttr.com (199.16.159.55)  91.589 ms


C:\Users\tldr>tracert www.twitter.com

Tracing route to twitter.com [199.59.148.10]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.130.193.2
  2     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  x.x.x.x
  3     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  [x.x.x.x]
  4     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  [x.x.x.x]
  5    60 ms     1 ms     1 ms  [x.x.x.x]
  6    60 ms     1 ms     1 ms  204.255.173.54
  7     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  vlan51.ebr1.NewYork2.Level3.net [4.69.138.222]
  8     8 ms     8 ms     8 ms  ae-3-3.ebr2.Washington1.Level3.net [4.69.132.89]
  9     8 ms     8 ms    10 ms  ae-72-72.csw2.Washington1.Level3.net [4.69.134.150]
 10     9 ms    10 ms     9 ms  ae-2-70.edge2.Washington4.Level3.net [4.69.149.80]
 11     8 ms     8 ms     8 ms  TWITTER-INC.edge2.Washington4.Level3.net [4.53.114.102]
 12    68 ms    68 ms    68 ms  ae60.pao1-cr1.twttr.com [199.16.159.85]
 13    96 ms    73 ms    73 ms  xe-10-0-0.smf1-er1.twttr.com [199.16.159.49]
 14    73 ms    73 ms    73 ms  r-199-59-148-10.twttr.com [199.59.148.10]

Trace complete.
```

I'm not up to date on my networking / routing skills so can someone educate me on the options I have for

Answer (score 1):

I would use [mtr](http://www.bitwizard.nl/mtr/) to perform a traceroute to the destination and see where the packet loss increases significantly.

Comment: Please keep in mind, many providers have down circuits and overloaded paths in the NYC area right now. Your results may be influenced by that.

Comment: +1. "increase" is the important word here. Localized packet loss does not matter (routers protect themselves) but an increase might indicate an overloaded or defective path.